# Gmail is not auto syncing on the computer

Tags: gmail

I had someone ask me about a problem that just started. They open Chrome on their computer and go to Gmail. The view that comes up is the inbox. What he said use to happen is that he could work on other things and Gmail would continue to update in the background and display new items in his inbox automatically. Now that has stopped. He has to manually check for new items.

I tried the same thing on my computer with my Gmail account and indeed new items were automatically displayed in my inbox even thought I was working on other things at the time.

Googling said there should be some kind of auto sync setting but darn if I can find it. Can someone tell me how to correct this problem?

Comment: Are you using Chrome too or an installable email client? What is the OS of your computer?

Comment: This is the problem I had Googling too. The original question stated very clearly "They open Chrome on their computer and go to Gmail" yet none of the comments below address the settings from within Chrome and Gmail ON A COMPUTER. All the comments below assume erroneously that he is using a phone.

Comment: Possible related: [youtube stops playing when switching chrome tab](https://superuser.com/q/1204222/152004)

Answer (score -1):

There's a sync option in the settings for all features. And auto delete. You can manually set your sync for minutes, days, weeks, and maybe you need to update your chrome, gmail, and Google Play. If that doesn't work force stop uninstall and reload.